# Does ColdFusion has any in built binary search function?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I was wondering whether ColdFusion uses any binary search algorithm for searching? Does anyone of you have any idea on in-built functions and what they use?

Comment: I would use the `find()` or `filter()` and then see how they scale.

OR

I would go to Lucee and dive into its source code to see how they implemented it.

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Thank you for your response. find() will be linear and I wanted to use the binary search algorithm. I had written my own function, however, wondering how ColdFusion does it and how come ColdFusion doesn't have any inbuilt function for this. I have no idea about Lucee, could you guide me through it so that I would like to check it once? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Lucee well enough to find. You may want to consider putting in an issue with  https://tracker.adobe.com/ maybe they will build something someday, or at least explain why they don't have it.

Comment: If you really think it is needed, you could also look into using java. Its Collections lib offers binary search functions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Coldfusion lets you use anything in the Java standard library.

```
<cfset arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]>
<cfset collections = createObject('java', 'java.util.Collections')>
<cfdump var="#collections.binarySearch(arr, 3)#">
```

Keep in mind that the returned value is zero-indexed, while CF is one-indexed.

You may need to do more complicated conversions depending on the data types inside your array, and of course the array must be sorted before you use binarySearch.

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Sometimes, yes.  Java's binarySearch is more picky than CF. Array elements must be of the same type of you get a ClassCastException.  Also, **the array must be sorted** or the results are undefined.

Comment: Is there a way to look at the built-in function(s) code implementation just like Java?

Comment: Lucee yes. Because it is open source. Adobe CF, no. Unless you work for Adobe.

Comment: Tim, may want to mention arrays *must* be sorted first, or it won't work as expected.

Comment: No conversions are necessary in this case; the above code runs fine in Adobe CF.